# Do jquery styles change after the css class changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery, and I was looking at the `.css()` function. I also looked at the `.addClass()` and the `.removeClass()`. If I use `.css()`, on a element and then I change the element's class, would the element still have the styles that I put from `.css()`? Here is some example code:

```
$(".myClass").css({
    "someStyle": "someValue"
});
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".myClass").removeClass("myClass");
    // Do the styles still exist?
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Answer is _No_.

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid using `css()` unless there is literally no alternative. It ties the JS and UI styling logic toghether too tightly, when they should be as separate as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is *No*.

The function `.css()` add inline styles to the DOM element, even if the class is remove later it will have no effect with the CSS rule applied using `.css()` method.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
$(".myClass").css({
    "someStyle": "someValue"
});
```

is not adding those styles to the class `myClass`. It's doing two completely separate and unrelated things:

1. Looking up elements using a CSS selector (in this case, a class selector), and
2. Adding styles to those elements directly (e.g., to the elements' `style` objects).

Removing the class later has no effect on the styles directly attached to the elements.